# Why pushing an element in vector outside the main function gives error?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am confused about why am I getting this error when I am pushing elements from outside of the `main` function though it works perfectly if I push it from the inside.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> vect;
vect.push_back(1);

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
main.cpp:6:1: error: ‘vect’ does not name a type
 vect.push_back(1);
 ^~~~
```

I think I have included `std namespace` so it shouldn't throw an error. Could somebody please help me out?

Comment: You can't put arbitrary statements at the top level in C++. This sort of logic should be inside a function. If it's intended to initialize, you could provide an initializer for `vect` instead.

Comment: You can't just put code outside functions.